# Best Approach to Handle User Rights in Desktop Applications

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently developping some desktop applications (WinForm) with a couple of screens, however i need to handle user rights.

> **Desktop Application :**
>
> Screen : Customers (GridView) (View/Edit/Create)

Some users are allowed to View only Customers, but some other users are allowed to Edit/Create Customers.

How can i implement a "screen user rights" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Barely an answer (hence comment) - but by using the principal/identity model and IsInRole? Next job: write your principal/identity layer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# WinForms User/Permission management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267952/c-sharp-winforms-user-permission-management)