# Role Based Table Structure c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I was wondering what everyone thinks is a good structure for role based permissions on form crud operations. I need to be able to store against per group if their administrator , managers or other users I was thinking the solution here [C# WinForms User/Permission management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267952/c-sharp-winforms-user-permission-management)

Is good enough but I need to be able to disable the add edit delete buttons on fly I don't want to have four records for each operation I want to add one permission record per screen per user what is my best approach c#

Comment: Read this to understand why to stay away from role-based authorization http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/

Comment: ITS MORE  A REQUIREMENT manager users and guests its something I have to stick with